# variable inside a while loop

Tags: shell

$VAR2 works fine but $VAR1 returns

> shuf: invalid option -- 'c' Try 'shuf --help' for more information.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="shuf -n 1 file | head -c 5"
VAR2="shuf -n 1 file"
FILE="data"

while IFS="  " read -r COL1 COL2; do
    echo "$($VAR1) $($VAR2) $COL1 $COL2"
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: Please let us know what you want to achieve with this. Do you want to get the first five characters from a random line in a file? If so, why the loop? In general, it's usually a _really_ bad idea to store commands in variables.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to store command output in a variable is:

```
VARIABLE="$(command)"
```

Alternatively, the "old way" (note the backticks):

```
VARIABLE=`command`
```

Your code probably will work in this form (haven't tested it myself):

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="$(shuf -n 1 file | head -c 5)"
VAR2="$(shuf -n 1 file)"
FILE="data"

while IFS=" " read -r COL1 COL2; do
    echo "$VAR1 $VAR2 $COL1 $COL2"
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: That looks reasonable. The only thing is the double space in `$IFS` (the `IFS` variable holds a collection of characters, not really a string or expression).

Comment: @Kusalananda You're right, corrected. I hadn't had a need to use IFS myself yet. Am i correct to think, that if OP's data file contains only 2 strings per line, divided by whitespace, IFS is unnecessary? I imagine something like: `my\first\col my\2nd\col` (hence `read -r`).

Comment: Yes. `$IFS` does by default contain space, tab and newline. If there are more than two columns, `$COL1` will be the first column and `$COL2` will contain all the rest. One may want to set `IFS` to a space if a column contains tabs.